# How to fix 'NameError' in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I have some code. When User write "Date" in input line, output must be date, like 2019-06-8 16:34:40
but program can not find input text - name 'date' is not defined

```
import datetime

x = input("Type your question here ... ")
########## Date ##########
now = datetime.datetime.now()
date = "Date"
if x == date:
  print "Current date and time:"
  print str(now)

########## (Can't find anything) ##########
else:
  print("Something goes wrong ;( ")
```

Error - 
NameError: name 'date' is not defined

Comment: are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: Try changing your if condition to `if x == 'Date':`

Comment: for python 2 changing `input` to `raw_input` works, for python 3 changing `print` to use `()` works

Comment: are you sure this is the exact code you are running? As it sits, that `if` statement should be valid (missing parentheses notwithstanding)

Comment: @depperm i use Py 2 v.

Comment: @GiddharthSupta  there is no difference

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3

```
import datetime

x = input("Type your question here ... ")
########## Date ##########
now = datetime.datetime.now()
date = "Date"
if x == date:
  print ("Current date and time:")
  print (str(now))

########## (Can't find anything) ##########
else:
  print("Something goes wrong ;( ")
```

and the output is:

```
Type your question here ... Date                                                                                                                              
Current date and time:                                                                                                                                        
2019-07-08 12:53:41.534617
```